# Django formsets

Tags: django, django-forms, formsets

I'm making a survey site with django. I am pretty newbie with django so I apologize in advance if I can not explain well. My question focuses on the following models:

```
class SurveyType(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name    

class Question(models.Model):

    ANSWERTYPE_CHOICES = (
        (u'T', u'Text'),
        (u'R', u'Range'),
        (u'M', u'Media'),
    )

    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    surveytype = models.ForeignKey(SurveyType)

    answertype = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ANSWERTYPE_CHOICES)

    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question        


class Survey(models.Model):

    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

    surveytype = models.ForeignKey(SurveyType)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.course, self.surveytype) 

class Answer(models.Model):

    answer = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.answer
```

Django receives survey id. With the survey id it gets the surveytype and shows questions that must be displayed.

```
def survey(request, survey_id):
    survey_data = get_object_or_404(Survey, pk=survey_id)
    survey_type = survey_data.surveytype
    questions = Question.objects.all().filter(surveytype = survey_type).order_by('order')
```

I have read the django documentation about formsets but I don't understand what I have to write in forms.py, so I can't call the form in views.py to render de form in the template that shows the questions and write the answers in the answer model.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using modelforms and a foor loop.

Models.py

```
class Question(models.Model): 
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surveytype = models.ForeignKey(SurveyType)
    answertype = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
    limit_choices_to = Q(name='text answer', app_label='surveys')| \
    Q(name='media answer', app_label='surveys')| \
    Q(name='range answer', app_label='surveys'))

class RangeAnswer(models.Model):
    answer = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES_RANGE, default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s'%(self.answer)

class TextAnswer(models.Model):
    answer= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s'%(self.answer)

class MediaAnswer(models.Model):
    answer= models.ForeignKey(Media)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s'%(self.answer)
```

Forms.py

```
class RangeAnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RangeAnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['answer'].label = "Mi valoración"    
    class Meta:
        model = RangeAnswer
        widgets = {
            'answer': forms.RadioSelect(renderer=RadioRenderer)
        } 
RangeAnswer.form = RangeAnswerForm

class MediaAnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MediaAnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['answer'].label = "Medio"    
    class Meta:
        model = MediaAnswer
MediaAnswer.form= MediaAnswerForm

class TextAnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TextAnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['answer'].label = "Respuesta"    
    class Meta:
        model = TextAnswer
TextAnswer.form = TextAnswerForm
```

Views.py

```
for q in questions :
    q.form = q.answertype.model_class().form(prefix="%s"%q.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you import the form to your views.py?

After that you just have to create a view that will pass the form to a template.

For example in the views.py

```
def your_form(request):
    form = RegisterForm()
    return render_to_response('your_template.html', {'form': form}, RequestContext(request))
```

and then in your template you can render the form simply by writing

```
{{ form }}
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I don't know what to write in forms.py. Django documentation shows how to work with forms that use one or two models, not four :S. The problem I have is to create the form.py